# Why can't 10K users search for others' deleted posts?

Tags: discussion, search, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, deleted-posts

I have been trying to get to 10 thousand reputation for a while on Science Fiction & Fantasy (taking a while :P) but learned something weird a few weeks ago: users with 10,000 reputation can't search for others' deleted posts.

**What is the point of this? If those users are able to see the questions, why make it hard to find the questions to see?**

That's like giving someone in the government a lot of security clearance, but not letting them into DC except if they find a link to there (weird analogy).

Answer (score 1):

They're called deleted posts for a reason: they are **deleted**, since they do not belong on the site.

From the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> #### Viewing deleted posts
>
> You now have privileged access to posts that have been removed, either by their authors, by users with access to moderator tools, by moderators, or by the system.
>
> Use this privilege wisely:
>
> - Make sure what is being deleted should have been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community and/or moderator team.
> - Watch for signs of abuse being obscured by deletion.
> - Don't abuse this privilege to stir up trouble when someone has wisely decided to remove a problematic post.

None of these require being able to search for deleted posts; there's a [Delete votes overview](/tools?tab=delete) in the Moderation Tools (also accessible at 10k reputation) which suffices for this.